# Installed Windows on Mac, now want to go back to OS X

Tags: macos, imac, windows, partition

I tried to revert back to OS X, but I can't boot into recovery, or USB. It shows the prohibited symbol (a circle with a line through).

I thought it was a good idea to install Windows on a Mac, but it turns out it's a terrible idea (driver issues, slow downs, overheating).

What should I do?

I think my hard drive partitions are messed up.

I used this guide to install windows 7
http://derekhat.com/install-vista-on-a-macbook-without-bootcamp/

Comment: Did you try Internet Recovery?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I get the apple logo, and the prohibitory symbol appears.

Comment: Wow, you picked instructions for installing Vista! You do need help. Apple make changes to the Mac designs with each model released. To help you properly, you would need to add the following information to your question: 1) Model/year of your Mac? 2) Version of macOS (OS X) you wish to install? 3) Any OS X installation DVDs you may have? 4) Does you model have a working DVD drive? 5) does the Windows 7 include any Service Packs? 6) Was Windows 7 a 32 bit or 64 bit version? 7) do you have any other working Mac to download file? If so, what model/year and version of macOS (OS X)?

Comment: @DavidAnderson  1. 2012 MC309LL  2. EL Capitan  3. No installation disks for mac at the moment  4. Dvd drive is working  5. No service packs  6. Windows 7 64 bit I have no other mac arounds, unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure you iMac is a 2012 model? [This web site](https://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MC309LL) shows your iMac is a 2011 model. Are you sure your Windows 7 does not contain any service packs. I ask because according to this [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016),  Windows 7 has to have Service Pack 1 (SP1) in order to correctly install on any Mac. By the way, if the identifier is correct, then I as using the exact same model iMac. I can tell you for certain, that when correctly installed, Windows 7 and 10 both work great on this model/year iMac.

Comment: @DavidAnderson yes, the link you sent me is the exact model. I thought it was 2012 but its actually a mid-2011 mac. I checked my Windows 7 installation, and it does install SP1 by default.

Comment: I wonder if you installed the correct version of the Boot Camp Support Software. You should have downloaded and installed [version 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US).  Also, you must install using a BIOS boot method. You may get the Mac to boot using the EFI method, but you will encounter problems because many of the Boot Camp Support Software drivers are designed only the BIOS boot method.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I have not used bootcamp at all. I formatted the drive using disk utility, booted into a windows cd, and installed Windows on to that hard drive. At the time I installed it, windows worked well, but now my mac is running very slow, and I suspect it to be from windows. I want to transform it back into a mac with the latest version, OS X El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

### Reinstall macOS (OS X)

1. Boot to  Internet Recovery. See instructions below. You may need to reset your NVRAM. If so, see instructions below.
2. Use the Disk Utility app to erase the internal drive. Choose for `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` for the format.
3. Install macOS (OS X).
4. Boot to macOS (OS X).
5. If the operating system is Snow Leopard and the version is not 10.6.8, then download and install this [Mac OS X 10.6.8 Update Combo v1.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_ASIA).
6. If the operation system is 10.6.8, then install this [Mac App Store Update for OS X Snow Leopard](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1860?locale=en_US)
7. [Upgrade to 10.11.6](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886).

### Start up from macOS (OS X) Recovery over the Internet

1. Turn on or restart your Mac, then immediately hold down the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination.
2. Release the keys when you see the Apple logo or a spinning globe.
3. When you see the macOS (OS X) Utilities window, you have finished booting.

### Reset your computer’s NVRAM or PRAM

1. Shutdown the Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: <kbd>option</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd>. You will need to press and hold these keys simultaneously in step 4.
3. Turn on your Mac.
4. Immediately press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combination, before the black screen with the Apple logo appears.
5. Continue pressing the keys until your Mac restarts, about 15 seconds.
6. Release the keys.

### Appendix

[How to reset NVRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

[How to reinstall macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904)

[About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Comment: I tried the instructions, and I am still stuck in a white screen. Any tips https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NPaiCyIk2TShbACCi5gE5_JZYiQFPhPn/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: You can not use a Windows keyboard. You have to get an Apple keyboard. Basically, the Mac is ignoring the keys you are pressing.